# Get the the last value of each month in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

At my job I have to run a query (or should I say it would make my life 100 times easier) that returns 
-The sum of all payments of each month of the year
-The final balance at the end of each month.

To get the latter I need to select the 'ending_balance' column of the last record of each month. I have the sum already figured out, so the whole query would look like this

```
select 
extract(month from request_date):: integer as mon,
extract(year from request_date)::integer as year,
<missing logic here> 
sum(total_amount),
from my_table group by 1,2 order by 2
```

I've been looking for the answer on stackoverflow and other sites for half a day and I've figured out how to get the value for a SINGLE month and year via

```
select payer_id 
from my_table as last_payer 
where extract(month from request_date):: integer = '2' 
and extract(year from request_date)::integer= '2019' 
order by request_date desc limit 1
```

but this only works if I supply a specific date. I need something that does this for each month and year. Replacing the hardcoded values with 'mon' and 'year' does not work.

I'll also add that I'm working on dbeaver, which I don't think supports functions, but if functions are the only way I can do this I guess I'll switch over to just using the command line.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and your desired results. It's not super clear what *"find the `ending_balance` value of the last record of each month"* means. I'm betting that a correlated subquery, or a derived table would do the trick here, but I feel like I'm making some assumptions.

Comment: I don't really want to share info that is too specific to my jobs db but the 'ending balance' is simply the a value in each entry of the db.  So basically I want to select a column from the last entry of each month.

Comment: cant you simply use between operator between 2 dates? that way you have more control between the upper limit and lower limit and get what you want!

Comment: How would I do that so it would set the dates to the months on each row? I know how to supply specific dates, or use now(), but I don't know how I'd do it for each month in a year or for all time.

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you.

Specific month of every year.

```
select * from 
(select 
concat(extract(month from request_date):: integer,
extract(year from request_date)::integer) as dt
from table1) as a
group by dt
```

just add the `sum` of every group.